# Vue app hosted on vercel not hitting the api host on render

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cors, http-status-code-405

I've build a fully functional e-learning application with vue.js. This platform is powered by a RESTfull API build with Node.js/Express. The Frontend is hosted/deployed on [vercel](https://vercel.com/) while the backend is hosted on [render](http://render.com/).
The platform works well when run on localhost. When the frontend running on localhost access the backend endpoints hosted on render, everything seems to work find. But once i try to access it through the hosted frontend i get CORS error.

For instance this is the code which is incharge of performing a login

```
export const login = async (data: data) => {
  const logUser = axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "/api/v1/auth/login",
    data,
    params: {
      role: data.role,
    },
  });
  return logUser;
};
```

My front-end is hosted like on vercel.

When I used the axios baseUrl for all request to be made to that url CORS error was encounter right at development.

So the solution i tried was in my vue.config file I added a devSever with a proxy to my backend API. Like shown below

- vue.config.ts

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
devServer: {
proxy: "https://my-api-backend.onrender.com",
})
```

So my intention is for the browser to proxy all request to that API but what i does it it give me a **Method Not allowed 405** error. when i try to perform certain operation like login which is a post request to my back-end. It works well on development but has issues on production. It's seem as the request are instead proxied to my front-end were the Vue app is hosted instead of backend

It should be noted that the back-end allows all request to be handle no matter the source.

```
const app =express()
const cors = required('cors')

app(cors('*'))
```

CORS has be set to handle all request

What could i be missing.

Comment: I believe this is an issue specific to Render. Their setup apparently stands in the way of preflight. See https://twitter.com/Fourteia/status/1640577939518689280